# How to find values of a table type valueset using query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working in oracle apps and I want to fetch the values of a table type valueset . But I am not able to.

For independant valuesets, I use the below query:

```
SELECT flex_value
     INTO v_type_val
     FROM apps.fnd_flex_values_vl ffvv, apps.fnd_flex_value_sets ffvs
    WHERE ffvv.flex_value_set_id = ffvs.flex_value_set_id
      AND ffvs.flex_value_set_name = <Value Set Name>;
```

But using it for table type valuesets returns NULL

Please help me out

Comment: Do you receive an error? What are you missing?

Comment: When I am using the above code for a valueset that is of independant type...it is working fine and fetching values. But if we use it for a table type valueset it is returning NULL

Comment: I hope this helps [Table type value set](http://waqasora.blogspot.in/2012/11/validation-type-table-in-value-sets-in.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
select ffvs.flex_value_set_id ,
    ffvs.flex_value_set_name ,
    ffvs.description set_description ,
    ffvs.validation_type,
    ffvt.value_column_name ,
    ffvt.meaning_column_name ,
    ffvt.id_column_name ,
    ffvt.application_table_name ,
    FFVT.ADDITIONAL_WHERE_CLAUSE
FROM APPS.fND_FLEX_VALUE_SETS FFVS ,
    apps.FND_FLEX_VALIDATION_TABLES FFVT
WHERE FFVS.FLEX_VALUE_SET_ID = FFVT.FLEX_VALUE_SET_ID;
```